# Customizing the location of Apache Mac OS X user webroot

Tags: php, macos, apache, httpd.conf

I've have the built-in Apache with PHP running on Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite. Both localhost and localhost/*~username* work as expected.

What I just can't get to work properly is to move the webroot for my *username* to another folder than the default *Sites* under my user profile directory. The situation I actually want is not to have it under /Users/*username*/Sites but under /Users/*username*/Development/Sites.

My *username*.conf in /etc/apache2/users looks like this:

```
<Directory "/Users/[username]/Development/Sites/">
    AddLanguage en .en
    LanguagePriority en fr de
    ForceLanguagePriority Fallback
    Options +Indexes +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from localhost
     Require all granted
</Directory>
```

As a result I get a 403 Forbidden response to localhost/*~username* where it does work properly when removing the "Development" part of the directory. I do have the same index.php in both locations. Owner, group and permissions are set equally as well as shown below;

Both the forbidden and the working directories have the same permissions set.

The "forbidden" situation has a Development directory right under /Users/*username* ...

```
drwxr-xr-x   6 [user]  staff    204  7 sep 22:23 Development
```

... having a Sites folder under it ...

```
drwxr-xr-x   4 [user]  staff   136  7 sep 22:41 Sites
```

.. containing an index.php

```
-rw-r--r--@ 1 [user]  staff    21  7 sep 22:41 index.php
```

The working situation has a Sites directory right under /Users/*username* ...

```
drwxr-xr-x   7 [user]  staff    238 11 sep 21:37 Sites
```

.. containing an index.php

```
-rw-r--r--@  1 [user]  staff    21  7 sep 22:41 index.php
```

Anyone?

Comment: whats the property of the folder ? you must make sure nobody can read it `chmod o+x` on your folder should make the trick if not already set (make sure full path is accessible

Comment: Thanks @FredericHenri for your reply. I've added the permission info to the post. Besides performed chmod o+x on index.php afterwards but no result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already upgraded to El Capitan (10.11) but I assume this would have worked the same in Yosemite.

Apart from the settings in the opening post the */etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf* must be edited. In my case I edited

```
UserDir Sites
```

into

```
UserDir Development/Sites
```